# laravel5.7 login not working on aws ec2 instance

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, error-handling

Code is working from last 3 years, but suddenly login or any other request are not working it redirects me to default page without error message.
Same code is working on another server but on aws its misbehaving.

Note - Session is stored in database.

Users are stuck and chasing continuously. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the error log, PHP short tag open.. etc

Comment: Nothing found in error log

Comment: There were some lag between reader & writer database so session not created. After 12 hours of debugging found solution. As there was no change in infra/code so we were not thinking about replication lag.